# Why we need analysis_export when we have analysis_port

Tags: uvm

We usually need `analysis_export` for making data transfer from `analysis_port` to `analysis_imp`. They serve as a data transfer objects from ports to implementations, as we cannot connect `analysis_imp` to another `analysis_imp`.

However the `analysis_port`-s can be connected to other `analysis_port`-s.
So my questions is, why we need `analysis_export`, when instead of `analysis_export` we can just use `analysis_port`?

Comment: not sure that understood your explanation
Could you please take a look here: https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1a/html/files2/tlm1-txt.html, in "Usage" section. I want to know why instead of export not to use port object?

Comment: Export is something that **passively responds** to a request. On the other hand, port initiates the request. When the packet travels from `leaf1 `to `comp1`, the hierarchy changes hence *port-port* connection. Now, `comp1` and `comp2` are at same hierarchy, `comp2` only **responds** to request from `comp1`, hence it contains export. Similar comments apply for `comp2` to `subcomp2`, since both of them only *responds*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer
Sorry but I dont understand
What you mean saing passively responds?
if comp2 only responts to request from comp1, why it means that we need export?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the intention might have been the export interfaces are to be used for connections purpose only and the port interfaces are to be used to send the data -- port.write(data); [an export need not implement the write function ]

BUT the analysis_export and analysis_port seem to have very similar in implementation.
it also look like that can be also interchanged. The only difference it is the MASK/ type bit which say which type of interface it is - export / port . Other that this the interface implementation appears to be same.

The main difference is when the interfaces are being connected (connect function ) a check is implemented to the way connection can be made. port-to-port ,  port-to-export ,  port-to-imp , export-to-export ,  export-to-imp .
These might be used to ensure that we use export to propagate interfaces and finally connect them to some implementation. 
But from the current implementation it looks like both the port and export have write functions which can be called and they can be used interchangeably even for connections.

The only catch is once a port is connected to an export , it can only connect to other exports and has to terminate at a implementation. [ for some reason only a port-port connections does not generate any run time ]

Also is it possible at some time in the past they may might had different implementations [ just speculating , someone who has followed the history of UVM could answer that. ]